# can galaxy tab 2 gt-p5113 receive internet calls?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, sip

I have a samsung galaxy tab2 gt - p5113. i would like to use sipdroid to make internet calls. unfortunately i'm not able to find the call settings option to enable "Receive internet calls".

Is it posssible to make internet calls in this tab? if yes - how?

Answer (score -1):

Click on the phone menu, then click on the right side. There will be three options:

1. send message
2. speed dial setting
3. call setting